# SSRS Encryption Key

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Server with a bunch of reports on it... I was wondering if I backup my encryption key and restore it on another server that is connected to the same database, will my reports be transferred as well or will they remain on the original server? If I am not specific enough, please let me know and I can elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Well, when you tried it, what happened?

Comment: I haven’t tried doing it yet. I wanted to see if anyone knows the answer before I move forward with the process.